# Memory size exhausted on customer login

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Some time ago some customers of my site started to experience login problems: after clicking login button they need to wait for like few minutes and then this error show up

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1015

After that i got this problem on every page although before it was working fine.

I think the problem is in cookies because i got 2 sites in on magento and on different domains and one of then is working fine. I need to fix it but have no idea how.

I have tried to change cookie domain in backend but it didn't help. Same with changing cookie save path - after this i can not login at all, just got redirect on the same page.

Comment: Could you solve this issue?